# Play upload File (Database and assets)

Tags: playframework-2.0

Users need to upload some images files from a form.
This images files need to be saved to public/ folder.
And i need to have a view to display this images too. (from URL ?, assets ?)
How can i proceed ?
I need to save the file name in my database ? (image.png?) The Path ? ("public/images/image.png"?) The URL file ? (IE localhost/assets/images/image.png?)

If i save the URL, how can i get the file f i need to delete it later.
If i save the public path how can i get the URL from ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a column in table say `image_name` set its default value say `default.png`.
2. Create a folder in public folder say `images`.
3. Save a default image in `/public/images/default.png` (same name as default name saved to database).So if the the user dint have any uploaded image a default image is shown.
4. To upload image get the image from form :

   a. Change image name to something like `1.png`(where `1` is the id of that user which would be different for other user.You can also choose some unique token ) and save the image to the direcctory `/public/images/`.

   b. Then update the column `image_name` in database this time its `1.png`.
5. Access the image in page by:

`<img src="@routes.Assets.at("images/"+user.image_name)" alt="your image"  />`

where user is User object and image_name varible name(column name).So each time you pass different user object and display their related images.

Now if you want to delete.Do

```
String imagePath = Play.application().path().getPath() + "/public/images";
```

The above will give you image path,
get image name from database and delete the image(you can use file.delete()).